# Changing overlay layers when switching base layer

Tags: leaflet

I have built a leaflet map with two base layers, and each of these base layers will have their own unique points of interest. The points of interest are being stored as geojson that I loop over to create multiple overlays for different categories.  So when viewing the default base layer you would see layers for Show All, Cat1, Cat2 etc.

I need a way to be able to attach overlay layers to a base layer, or remove all overlay layers and then load the relevant ones when the base layer changes.

I tried using the following, which worked to switch categories, with the baselayerchange event, but the overlay layers were still displaying when I switched base layers.

```
layerControl._layers.forEach(function(layer){
  if(layer.overlay){
    map.removeLayer(layer.layer)
  }
});
```

I've been searching for a couple of days now for an answer to this without any luck, any help is greatly appreciated.

### EDIT

Posting additional code for context. This is not the entirety of the code, there are some plugins that I'm not including code for and have excluded definitions for a several variables, but this should provide better insight into how things are working.

```
//Initialize the map
var map = new L.Map('map', {
maxZoom: mapMaxZoom,
minZoom: mapMinZoom,
crs: crs1848,
attributionControl: false,
layers: [pano1848]
});

//add controls to the map
 var layerControl = L.control.layers(null, null, {position: 'bottomleft'}).addTo(map);

//building category layers from geojson
    var types = ['African Americans', 'Art Architecture Culture', 'Education Religion Reform', 'Everyday Life', 'Immigrants', 'Science Inventions', 'Transportation Industry Commerce'];
types.forEach(function(type){
  var catType = type.replace(/\s/g,"");
  var catPoints = L.geoJson(mapData, {
      filter: function(feature, layer){
        var cat = feature.properties['category'];
        return cat.indexOf(catType) >= 0;
      },
      onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
      layer.bindTooltip(feature.properties.name);

      (function(layer, properties){
        //Create Numeric markers
        var numericMarker = L.ExtraMarkers.icon({
          icon: 'fa-number',
          markerColor: 'yellow',
          number: feature.properties['id']
        });
        layer.setIcon(numericMarker);

        layer.on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
          url:feature.properties['url'],
          dataType:'html',
          success: function(result){
            $('#detailContainer').html(result);
            $('#overlay').fadeIn(300);
          }
        });
      });   
      })(layer, feature.properties);
    }
  });
  layerControl.addOverlay(catPoints, catType);
});
  
  //Base Layer Change Event
  map.on('baselayerchange', function(base){
  var layerName;

  layerControl._layers.forEach(function(layer){
    if(layer.overlay){
      map.removeLayer(layer.layer)
    }
  });


  if(base._url.indexOf('1848') >= 0){
    map.options.crs = crs1848;
    map.fitBounds([
      crs1848.unproject(L.point(mapExtent1848[2], mapExtent1848[3])),
      crs1848.unproject(L.point(mapExtent1848[0], mapExtent1848[1]))
    ]);
    var southWest = map.unproject([0, 8192], map.getMaxZoom());
    var northEast = map.unproject([90112, 0], map.getMaxZoom());
    map.setMaxBounds(new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast));
    map.addLayer(allPoints);
    layerName = '1848 Panorama';
  }
  else if(base._url.indexOf('2018') >= 0){
    map.options.crs = crs2018;
    map.fitBounds([
      crs2018.unproject(L.point(mapExtent2018[2], mapExtent2018[3])),
      crs2018.unproject(L.point(mapExtent2018[0], mapExtent2018[1]))
    ]);
    var southWest = map.unproject([0, 8192], map.getMaxZoom());
    var northEast = map.unproject([49152, 0], map.getMaxZoom());
    map.setMaxBounds(new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast));
    layerName = '2018 Panorama'
  } 


  miniMap.changeLayer(minimapLayers[layerName]);
  //map.setView(map.getCenter(), map.getZoom());
});
```

Comment: Care to share more of your code? That snippet looks sane, but lacks context.

Comment: Thanks @peeebeee, I've updated the post to show a clearer picture of what i'm doing. Let me know if there's anything else I can post that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create **global variable** call "overlays", and remove it like an example below.

Here is the similar example to illustrate your problem **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/357/)**

```js
var overlays = {
  'Name 1': catPoints,
  'Name 2': catType
};

L.control.layers(null, overlays).addTo(map);

// Whenever you want to remove all overlays:
for (var name in overlays) {
  map.removeLayer(overlays[name]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this led me to find that I was having a problem with a zoomend event that was re-adding layers after they had been removed. I much prefer this approach to looping over the layercontrol itself.